# Locking and Simple Caching

Tags: c#, .net, iis, collections, locking

I have the following code. When deployed to a server, i m getting exception that , **this object already exists in the dictionary**. Even though , i did double locking, synchrony didnt work quite well. What s the best way to implement this? How can i best lock access to this section? Should i implement a singleton class and place the methods in there?

Should i lock the collection or mutex?

**NO I M NOT ON .NET 4**

As you can see, i m trying to do a simple cache based on datetime.

```
         // within the class.
         IDictionary<id, MyObj> _mydict = new Dictionary<string, MyObj>();
         object mutex = new object;

         //within some method comes the following

         if (_mydict.TryGetValue(id, out myobj))
         {
             DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
             DateTime expiry = myobj.Timestamp;
             TimeSpan span = now.Subtract(expiry);
             if (span.Minutes  0)
             {
                 lock (mutex)
                 {
                     myobj= DataAccess.GetMyObj(id);
                     _mydict[id] = myobj;
                 }

                 return myobj;
             }
             else
             {
                 return myobj;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             lock (mutex)
             {
                 if (_mydict.TryGetValue(id, out myobj))
                 {
                     return myobj;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     lock (mutex)
                     {
                         myobj = DataAccess.GetMyObj(id);
                         _mydict[id] = myobj;
                     }

                     return myobj;
                 }                    
             }
         }
```

Comment: Should the second-to-last line of code be `_myDict.Add(id, myobj)`?

Comment: does it matter? i was getting "this item is already in the collection" that s why i made that.

Comment: It's hard to tell what matters if we can't see  **exactly** what you're doing.

Comment: Are you completely sure there is no more code that calls .Add on the dictionary or manipulate it in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary isn't threadsafe to read from, you should lock before even calling TryGetValue, basically if you are using a Dictionary only one thing can touch it at a time

Comment: dude, why would u lock the whole dictionary for a look up? then what s the point of using a dictionary on a multithreaded environment, if it will work like a singleton ???????

Comment: This post has a good explanation of why double checked locking doesn't work with Dictionary.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624301/how-to-show-that-the-double-checked-lock-pattern-with-dictionarys-trygetvalue-is

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .Net 4 using the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) class should be quite helpful. It will take care of the locking for you.

Comment: Generally [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx) namespace has a lot of cool datastructures, not many people use them. :(

Comment: Should _mydict[name] = myobj; be _mydict[id] = myobj; in the first block of code?  Should _internetServiceProviderCache[id] = myobj; be _mydict[id]?

Answer (score 2):

Just use ASP.Net caching instead (you don't need to be creating a web application for this to work, just add a reference to `System.Web`):

```
void get(string key)
{
    return HttpRuntime.Cache[key];
}
void set(string key, object value, DateTime expires)
{
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
        key, 
        value, 
        null, 
        expires, 
        Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
}
```

Simple, easy and also means that your cache now also has all the other features of the ASP.Net cache (A cap on cache size, caching dependencies etc...)

Comment: I'd agree, the built in ASP.NET caching in the System.Web namespace works very well and keeps you from having to write all of this stuff yourself.  The Caching Application block also works quite well.

Comment: @user177883 Why? Its been part of the .Net framework since version 2.0 and is completely independent of the ASP.Net framework other than the reference to System.Web.

Comment: Check out this link.  On .NET 4.0 you can use the ObjectCache instead of the ASP.NET cache.  The Framework documentation recommends only using the HttpRuntime cache in ASP.NET applications.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx

Comment: @rsbarro Very useful looking - alas the poster and I are both stuck using antiquated technology (.Net 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using a list, and insert an item that is a class with your value and the timestamp that you inserted the value.  Then you can search for the latest timestamp and value, order the resulted list, and use the top item.  You can then expire the old items as you see fit.

Comment: Right, using a dictionary confines you to searching for a simple key. If you use a list _and_ use the value and a timestamp to search, then you don't have to worry about multiple insertions. Your problem then becomes about how to expire the old entries in the cache that aren't being used.